# The parameter name '' has already been declared. Parameter names must be unique

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have here an API created in NodeJS. When I run the API, it works on the first time, but if run it again its give me an error `The parameter name Username has already been declared. Parameter names must be unique at Request.input`. I checked other threads on how to fix this thing. Some answers that it needs to be cleared, but I think there is no function in NodeJS `mssql` library that clears parameter.(correct me if I'm wrong)

My code:

```
const res = require("express/lib/response")
const {sql,request} = require("../config/connection")

module.exports = {
checkExist: (data,callBack) => {
   
    if(data.key == process.env.KEY) {

        var username = data.username
        var firstname = data.firstname
        var middlename = data.middlename
        var lastname = data.lastname

        if(username == "" || firstname == "" || middlename == "" || lastname == "") {
            return callBack("Invalid Input")
        }
        else {
            request.input('Username', sql.VarChar(50), username);
            request.input('FirstName', sql.VarChar(50), firstname);
            request.input('MiddleName', sql.VarChar(50), middlename);
            request.input('LastName', sql.VarChar(50), lastname);
            request.output('Result', sql.Int);

            request.execute('sp_INS_User').then(function(recordsets, returnValue, affected) {
                if(recordsets.output.Result == -100) {
                    return callBack("Player Exist with different Username")
                }
                else if(recordsets.output.Result == -4) {
                    return callBack("Something went wrong while processing your request, please try again later.")
                }
                else {
                    if(recordsets.output.Result == 1000) {
                        return callBack(null,recordsets)
                    }
                }
               
                // console.dir(err);
              }).catch(function(err) {
                //return callBack(err)
                return callBack("Something went wrong while processing your request, please try again later.")
           });
        }
       

    }
    else {
            return callBack("Invalid Access")
    }
}

}
```

My code in : `../config/connection/`

```
const sql = require("mssql")
require("dotenv").config()

const sqlConfig = {
user: process.env.USER,
password: process.env.PASS,
database: process.env.DB_MAIN,
server: process.env.HOST,
pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
},
options: {
    encrypt:false,
    trustServerCertificate: true
}

}

const con = sql.connect(sqlConfig).then(function() {

console.log(`Database connection successful!`);

}).catch(function(err) {
console.log(`Database connection ${err}!`);

});

const request = new sql.Request();

module.exports = {
sql,request
}
```

Comment: This looks like an issue of reusing the `request` object so the second time this function gets called, you're using the same `request` object that was previously used the first time this function was called.  As such, you're registering duplicate names with `request.input()`.  You don't show the code for `require("../config/connection")` to know what the `request` object is for us to know what to suggest.  But, if you're creating some sort of new request object and then exporting it, then perhaps you need to export the ability to make a new one each time you want to use it.

Comment: Hi, I added the ```require("../config/connection")``` code.

Comment: Apparently, you will need a new copy of `const request = new sql.Request();` each time you want to use it because the error message is telling you that you can't repeat statements like ` request.input('Username',...)` over and over on the same request object.  So, export a function to get a new `request` object rather than exporting just one pre-made object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue of reusing the request object so the second time this function gets called, you're using the same request object that was previously used the first time this function was called. As such, you're registering duplicate names with `request.input()`.

Apparently, you will need a new copy of `const request = new sql.Request();` each time you want to use it because the error message is telling you that you can't repeat statements like  `request.input('Username',...)` over and over on the same request object.  So, export a function to get a new `request` object rather than exporting just one pre-made object.

You can do that like this:

../config/connection/

```
const sql = require("mssql")
require("dotenv").config()

const sqlConfig = {
user: process.env.USER,
password: process.env.PASS,
database: process.env.DB_MAIN,
server: process.env.HOST,
pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
},
options: {
    encrypt:false,
    trustServerCertificate: true
}

}

const con = sql.connect(sqlConfig).then(function() {

console.log(`Database connection successful!`);

}).catch(function(err) {
console.log(`Database connection ${err}!`);

});

const getRequest = function() { return new sql.Request(); };

module.exports = {
    sql, getRequest
};
```

And, your other code:

```
const res = require("express/lib/response")
const { sql, getRequest } = require("../config/connection")

module.exports = {
    checkExist: (data, callBack) => {

        const request = getRequest();

        if (data.key == process.env.CAMS_INPLAY_KEY) {

            var username = data.username
            var firstname = data.firstname
            var middlename = data.middlename
            var lastname = data.lastname

            if (username == "" || firstname == "" || middlename == "" || lastname == "") {
                return callBack("Invalid Input")
            } else {
                request.input('Username', sql.VarChar(50), username);
                request.input('FirstName', sql.VarChar(50), firstname);
                request.input('MiddleName', sql.VarChar(50), middlename);
                request.input('LastName', sql.VarChar(50), lastname);
                request.output('Result', sql.Int);

                request.execute('sp_INS_User').then(function(recordsets, returnValue, affected) {
                    if (recordsets.output.Result == -100) {
                        return callBack("Player Exist with different Username")
                    } else if (recordsets.output.Result == -4) {
                        return callBack(
                            "Something went wrong while processing your request, please try again later."
                            )
                    } else {
                        if (recordsets.output.Result == 1000) {
                            return callBack(null, recordsets)
                        }
                    }

                    // console.dir(err);
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    //return callBack(err)
                    return callBack(
                        "Something went wrong while processing your request, please try again later."
                        )
                });
            }


        } else {
            return callBack("Invalid Access")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi I think you missed to replace ```)``` to ```}``` on ```const getRequest = function() { return new sql.Request());``` but when I changed it, it works. Thank you

Comment: @momonsterrr - Yes, fixed now.